# Error Occured while trying to start Nightwatch Runner

Tags: javascript, nightwatch

I have successfully ran my test previously but now I am getting this error.

```
An error occurred while trying to start the Nightwatch Runner: Invalid testing environment specified: chrome\. Available environments are: chrome, firefox, edge
       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
       at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
```

I removed the Node directory and reinstalled. I added a . at the beginning of the path to webdrivers.

Comment: What did you set up in nightwatch.json under `test_settings->desiredCapabilities->browserName` ? and what are your settings under `cli_args` ?

Comment: I figured it out thanks!